# Iframe loading the base page after blazor publish

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a razor page in my application, accessed once I logged myself in the application via another razor page being the root of the application :

```
@page "test"
<div >
    <h3>This is a test</h3>
    <iframe src="./test.html" frameborder="0" id="test"></iframe>

</div>
```

The html file being just :

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>test </h3>
</body>
</html>```


 It correctly displays the test.html when I launch my blazor application in debug or release mode in visual studio.
But once I launch it after I published it, the iframe display the base page of the application, it's like the application inside the application, no idea why it is happening and the test.html is not displayed at all.
So basically the login page is displayed inside the iframe...

Any ideas how it is happening?
````

Comment: Is Blazor WASM standalone or with asp.net server? Did you check if the test.html file is copied on wwwroot published folder?

Comment: Is the `<base>` element path still valid for your `wwwroot` folder on the hosted environment?

Comment: The file is correctly output in the published folder and the base tag looks like this :     <base href="/" />
Sorry for the late reply, I was out